Tinymice editor strips <![endif --> tags
In um email templates i have used if mso tags to render a different logo image.
this is the sample code i have used. However everytime i save the template wordpress converts my <!–<![endif]–> into ‘& l t;!– . How can i avoid this.
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
            <img src="logo.png" alt="">
 <!--<![endif]-->

I tried using [‘entity_encoding’] = ‘raw’ setting in tinymice but no avail
Any help would be highly appreciated

it is not legal to have those as part of a post therefor your plugin has to do some work to support it. You should ask your plugin's support.

very indeed most noble sire. I shall ask the support
